# Display selected item in drop-down list

Tags: knockout.js

This seems like it should be simple to do, but it's proving troublesome. I'm trying to make text outside of a dropdown menu change depending on what item in the dropdown is selected. The context-sensitive portion of the code looks like this:

```
<h5 data-bind="visible: Values().Options == 0, text: 'a'"></h5>
<h5 data-bind="visible: Values().Options == 1, text: 'b'"></h5>
<h5 data-bind="visible: Values().Options == 2, text: 'c'"></h5>
```

Nothing shows up, but the odd thing is that when I do this:

```
<h5 data-bind="text: Values().Options"></h5>
```

Depending on which option is selected, either 0, 1, or 2 show up just as I would expect. What am I missing here?

Please note I'm fairly new to html.

Answer (score 0):

I created small piece of code for you. You can run it (use the button below) and see the result.

Also this article from official Knockout documentation might be useful for you: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html. It covers cases when you want to  apply Knockout bindings to the `<select>` input.

```js
function Item(arg) {  
  var self = this;
  
  self.value = arg.value;
  self.text = arg.text;
}

var viewModel = {      
  allItems: ko.observableArray([
    new Item({value: 0, text: 'a'}),
    new Item({value: 1, text: 'b'}),
    new Item({value: 2, text: 'c'})
  ]),
  
  selectedItem: ko.observable()
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<select data-bind="options: allItems, value: selectedItem, optionsText: 'value'"></select>

<h5 data-bind="text: selectedItem().text"></h5>
```